# How to setup Outlook to use connected phone to call contacts?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, telephony, your-phone

I have my smartphone and and Windows 10 PC connected to the same Microsoft account. My Smartphone does show up as a connected device on the PC. I can easily initiate phone calls with the phone from the PC using the Microsoft app "Your Phone".

I also have Outlook 365 installed. In the Windows 10 Settings -> Phone Calls, the setting to allow apps to make phone calls with the connected phone is enabled. But in the section where I am supposed to choose which apps should be allowed to do so, Outlook is not listed.

In Outlook when I click on a contact's phone number to initiate a call nothing happens. If I select to dial another number from the context menu in Outlook my MS-Teams app crashes.

How would I configure Outlook to dial using my connected phone? Do I need a TAPI TSP for that? Is there a TAPI TSP that can use the windows built in functionality to initiate calls with my connected phone or the "your phone" app?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a modem connected to a voice telephone line, you can use Microsoft Outlook to dial any phone number you specify. Please checking in to see if the information in this thread could be helpful to you: [Setting up dialing on MS Outlook 2010](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0602571a-60ea-422a-8acb-620fe750d4d3/setting-up-dialing-on-ms-outlook-2010?forum=officesetupdeployprevious).